# case_when() mutate in pipe but maintain original data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that I created a column on based on outside data. I have about 4 values that did not have a match in outside data, so they have 'NA' in my column. I want to fix the NAs manually using mutate() and case_when() but I cannot figure out how to tell my case_when() to maintain the data that is not starting as 'NA'. Example data below:

```
data(mtcars)
```

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(carb = case_when(
    cyl == 4 ~ 5000
  ))
```

```
cyl    carb
<dbl> <dbl>

6   NA          
6   NA          
4   5000            
6   NA          
8   NA          
6   NA          
8   NA          
4   5000            
4   5000            
6   NA
```

If this were my data, I would want the 5000 along with the original data in the 'carb' column.

Thank you!

Comment: `, TRUE~carb))` in `case_when`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately this issue is relatively trivial. In `case_when()` we check through a list of conditions in order, so if the second argument had the condition `TRUE` and we set if this condition is met the result to be `carb` we could attain our result.

I have produced an illustrative reprex below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(carb = case_when(
    cyl == 4 ~ 5000,
    TRUE ~ carb
  )) %>% 
  head(10)
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4 5000
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4 5000
#> Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4 5000
#> Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>